# How to have a big sigma and big zero inside the whole matrix

Tags: matrices

How can I achieve the following big sigma and big zero in a matrix:

[image]

Each of the symbols are there in place of a group of matrix elements and not one element. Suppose we divide matrix into two sections (column-wise), one section is called $\sigma$ and the other is showing that all elements are zero (hence a bog zero). So the following small equation is not what I need:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}\sum 0 \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: \LARGE, \huge and similars are not working?

Comment: Are you looking for `\displaystyle\sum`?

Comment: You should use `\Sigma` not `\sum` e.g. `\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma & 0 \end{bmatrix}` and it would help if you explained why you don't need your mwe.

Comment: Edited the question to add more details of what the desired output should be and what it looks like. @ManuelSchmidt

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Edited the question. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: From your question and comments I still don't know what exactly you want. You may get better answers I if you clearly state your requirements

Comment: I wouldn't use big things; if `\Sigma` stands for a matrix, just `\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma & 0\end{bmatrix}` will suffice; maybe a special symbol for a zero matrix may also help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following, maybe? (Feel free to change the sizes of the symbols by adjusting the first argument of the `\scalebox` directives.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'bmatrix' environment
\usepackage{graphicx} % for '\scalebox' macro
\newcommand\humongousZero{\scalebox{3}{$0$}}
\newcommand\humongousSigma{\scalebox{3}{$\Sigma$}}

\begin{document}
\[
abc 
    \begin{bmatrix}  
    & & & & \\
    & \humungousSigma & & \humungousZero & \\
    & & & &
    \end{bmatrix} 
xyz
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\bigZero{\mbox{\huge$0$}}
\newcommand\bigSigma{\mbox{\huge$\Sigma$}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix} \bigSigma & \bigZero \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

For getting arbitrary font size, you can extend the definition, but you also need to enable arbitrary font scaling.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}{
  <-7.5>    cmex7
  <7.5-8.5> cmex8
  <8.5-9.5> cmex9
  <9.5->    cmex10
}{}


\newcommand\bigZero[1][17]{\mbox{\fontsize{#1}{0}\selectfont$0$}}
\newcommand\bigSigma[1][17]{\mbox{\fontsize{#1}{0}\selectfont$\Sigma$}}
\begin{document}
\[
A=\begin{bmatrix} \bigSigma & \bigZero \end{bmatrix}\qquad
B=\begin{bmatrix} \bigSigma[48] & \bigZero[48] \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sort of. Couldn't it get any bigger than that? A big $m \times n$ matrix?